# R check if email address has multiple client IDs

Tags: r

I would like to check in R if an email address has multiple client IDs in a data frame.

```
client_ID email
1         a@a.com
2         a@a.com
3         b@b.com
3         b@b.com
```

Result I am looking for (a@a.com has multiple IDs):

```
client_ID email
1         a@a.com
2         a@a.com
```

How can I select the email addresses with multiple client IDs?

Comment: Maybe `?duplicated` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could also do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'email', `if` the `length` of `unique` number of 'client_ID' is greater than 1, we get Subset of Data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(client_ID) > 1) .SD, email]
#     email client_ID
#1: a@a.com         1
#2: a@a.com         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `df` is your data.frame and looks like this

```
> df
  client_ID   email
1         1 a@a.com
2         2 a@a.com
3         3 b@b.com
4         3 b@b.com
```

Then, a possible solution could be...

```
> result <- lapply(split(df, df$email), function(x) x[all(!duplicated(x$client_ID))] )
> result <- data.frame(result)
> names(result) <- names(df)
> result
  client_ID   email
1         1 a@a.com
2         2 a@a.com
```